# PhalconPHP - Groups of Routes

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I am using Phalcon Framework and would like to learn how to group routes.
The official documentation did not help me that much.

This is how my routes look like:

```
$app->get('/users', function() {
   // do something
});

$app->get('/users/{id}', function($id) {
   // do something
});

$app->post('/users', function() {
   // do something
});
```

I would like to group these routes under "users" group so the code will be more clear and structured.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi did you try [Using controllers as handlers](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html#using-controllers-as-handlers)?

Comment: yes but i don't want to create a controller instance as the main handler. i want my handler to be an anonymous function. is it possible using micro collection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm use collection to this. Code look something like.

```
$inbound = new Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection();
$inbound->setHandler('InboundController', true);
$inbound->setPrefix('/v1/inbound');
$inbound->get('/{req_no}', 'readAction');
$inbound->post('/', 'createAction');
$inbound->put('/{req_no}', 'updateAction');
$inbound->delete('/{req_no}', 'deleteAction');
```

Comment: what if i don't want to set handler? is it possible without setting handler? if yes - how?

Comment: Could http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html#generating-urls-for-routes is the answer?

Comment: Your previous answer is what i actually need. The problem is that i don't want to set any handler. I want this handler to be anonymous function.

Comment: Maybe split by namespace? Implement group of uri with same name space.

Comment: this is an option but not so convenient